# API hooking with Microsoft Detours

Tags: windows, api, ransomware, file-system

I want to hook certain API calls, e.g. **CreateFile** (or **NtCreateFile** if I hook `ntdll.dll`), but there are some issues.

I can use several methods to achieve this goal, e.g. DLL injection, Inline hooking etc. But I think the most pragmatic way would be to use Microsoft Detours, as it handles some functions, e.g. trampolines, for me.

However, the issue is that I don't know which processes I want to hook beforehand, so my custom DLL should be loaded into the virtual address space of the process, when the path of the DLL is set to `Kernel32.dll` or when it specifically calls for the functions CreateFile, ReadFile etc.

Since this is in the context of ransomware detection, I don't know which processes will invoke these API calls.. so actually, I want to have a system-wide hook. I read articles etc. about this topic, and one of the approaches is to change the registry entries, but then it will only work for processes that use `user32.dll`, have a GUI etc.

Can anyone advise me on this case? Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I did some additional research. I think inline hooking makes the most sense.

Comment: There's a reason that antivirus / antimalware uses a kernel driver.  Hooking just is not effective (malware can inline the syscall setup code and skip `kernel32.dll` or `ntdll.dll` for the calls it wishes to hide).